# How to custom error message when rule check occurred ? T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server 2016.
I created a column with User-Defined Data Type that binding Rule.
T-SQL script like:

```
CREATE RULE [dbo].[R_typeYesNo]
    AS @column IN ('Y', 'N')
GO

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[typeYesNo]
    FROM VARCHAR (1) NULL
GO

EXECUTE sp_bindrule [R_typeYesNo], [typeYesNo]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyRuleTable (
    ID                   int                  identity,
    ACTIVEYN             [dbo].[typeYesNo]     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_MyRuleTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.MyRuleTable(ACTIVEYN)
VALUES('A')
GO

-- Exception here 

DROP TABLE dbo.MyRuleTable;
DROP TYPE [dbo].[typeYesNo];
DROP RULE [dbo].[R_typeYesNo];
GO
```

When a wrong value inserted , the Rule check will return exception message:

> Msg 513, Level 16, State 0, Line 20  A column insert or update
>   conflicts with a rule imposed by a previous CREATE RULE statement. The
>   statement was terminated. The conflict occurred in database 'DB1',
>   table 'dbo.MyRuleTable', column 'ACTIVEYN'.

Is possible, can customize the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom error message for your Rules

```
EXEC sp_addmessage
500021,
10,
'This is a custom error message for MyRule'
```

And use that in `CATCH` block using `RAISERROR` or `THROW`

```
BEGIN try
     -- Exception here 
END try
BEGIN catch
    IF Error_message() LIKE '%MyRuleTable%'
      BEGIN
          RAISERROR (500021,10,1)
      END
    ELSE 
       BEGIN
           DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
           DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY();
           DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE();

           RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
       END
END catch
```